# What causes `AssertionError` when asserting a diagonalized vector in Julia?

Tags: julia, assertion

I've been doing some [exercises in julia](https://github.com/JuliaAcademy/JuliaTutorials/tree/main/introductory-tutorials/intro-to-julia), and I am currently trying to `@assert` a vector that has been diagonalized into a matrix against a "solution matrix" given in the exercise notebook. However, I get an `AssertionError` when asserting my code against the provided solution. Example of my code:

```
julia> using LinearAlgebra

julia> A =
[
 140   97   74  168  131
  97  106   89  131   36
  74   89  152  144   71
 168  131  144   54  142
 131   36   71  142   36
]

5×5 Matrix{Int64}:
 140   97   74  168  131
  97  106   89  131   36
  74   89  152  144   71
 168  131  144   54  142
 131   36   71  142   36

julia> A_eigv = eigen(A).values

5-element Vector{Float64}:
 -128.49322764802145
  -55.887784553057
   42.752167279318854
   87.16111477514494
  542.4677301466137

julia> A_diag = Diagonal(A_eigv)

5×5 Diagonal{Float64, Vector{Float64}}:
 -128.493     ⋅        ⋅        ⋅         ⋅ 
     ⋅     -55.8878    ⋅        ⋅         ⋅ 
     ⋅        ⋅      42.7522    ⋅         ⋅ 
     ⋅        ⋅        ⋅      87.1611     ⋅ 
     ⋅        ⋅        ⋅        ⋅      542.468

julia> @assert A_diag ==  [-128.493    0.0      0.0      0.0       0.0;
    0.0    -55.8878   0.0      0.0       0.0;
    0.0      0.0     42.7522   0.0       0.0;
    0.0      0.0      0.0     87.1611    0.0;
    0.0 0.0      0.0      0.0     542.468]

AssertionError: A_diag == [-128.493 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0; 0.0 -55.8878 0.0 0.0 0.0; 0.0 0.0 42.7522 0.0 0.0; 0.0 0.0 0.0 87.1611 0.0; 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 542.468]

Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope
   @ In[90]:1
 [2] eval
   @ ./boot.jl:360 [inlined]
 [3] include_string(mapexpr::typeof(REPL.softscope), mod::Module, code::String, filename::String)
   @ Base ./loading.jl:1094
```

My inital assumption was that a difference in number of decimals was the cause of the error. I therefore replaced `==` with `≈` (`\approx`). However, as the code example below shows, the error persists:

```
julia> @assert A_diag ≈ #\approx
[-128.493    0.0      0.0      0.0       0.0;
    0.0    -55.8878   0.0      0.0       0.0;
    0.0      0.0     42.7522   0.0       0.0;
    0.0      0.0      0.0     87.1611    0.0;
    0.0 0.0      0.0      0.0     542.468]

AssertionError: A_diag ≈ [-128.493 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0; 0.0 -55.8878 0.0 0.0 0.0; 0.0 0.0 42.7522 0.0 0.0; 0.0 0.0 0.0 87.1611 0.0; 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 542.468]

Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope
   @ In[97]:1
 [2] eval
   @ ./boot.jl:360 [inlined]
 [3] include_string(mapexpr::typeof(REPL.softscope), mod::Module, code::String, filename::String)
   @ Base ./loading.jl:1094
```

I've been reading through my code multiple times now, and I am at a loss. The values in my diagonal matrix (`A_diag`) are seemingly identical to the solution matrix. Furthermore, setting the statement to approximately equal (`\approx`) renders the same error, so I assume I can count out decimal error.

My main question is: **What causes the `AssertionError`?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the dots are treated as 0 for the purpose of testing equality.

```
julia> Diagonal(1:2) == [1 0; 0 2]
true
```

Your problem is that your arrays are actually *not* equal; `-128.49322764802145` is not the same as `-128.493`. (The pretty-printed version of the array truncates floats for display, but that's not the true underlying value!).

[Edit:]

Using `≈` (`\approx`) will also fail in this case. The reason for this is explained in the documentation for `isapprox()`

> The binary operator `≈` is equivalent to `isapprox` with the default arguments,

> if an `atol > 0` is not specified, `rtol` defaults to the square root of eps of the type of `x` or `y`, whichever is bigger (least precise).

Essentially, what this means is that `≈` will test for approximate equality with a relative tolerance of `√eps()` which is approximately equal to 1.5e-8, or 0.0000015%. This tolerance is waaay too low, and increasing the tolerance will resolve the issue. E.g.:

```
# Option 1: Absolute tolerance. Set to a reasonable max deviation:
julia> isapprox(A_diag, sol_mat, atol = 1e-3)
true

# Option 2: Relative tolerance. Setting rtol = 1e-n, n is the number of significant digits in either matrices will work in most cases.
julia> isapprox(A_diag, sol_mat, rtol = 1e-6)
true
```

Since the solution matrix provides the values in six significant digits, another alternative is to round the values in `A_diag` to this number og digits and test for equality. E.g.:

```
julia> round.(A_diag, RoundNearestTiesUp, sigdigits=6) == 
[-128.493    0.0      0.0      0.0       0.0;
    0.0    -55.8878   0.0      0.0       0.0;
    0.0      0.0     42.7522   0.0       0.0;
    0.0      0.0      0.0     87.1611    0.0;
    0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0     542.468]
true
```

Comment: I failed to mention I already tried using `\approx` with the same outcome. I have updated the post to elaborate on this. I also rephrased the question, as you're right that the dots are evaluated to zero (as they should be).

Comment: @PålBjartan you have to set the tolerance of approx s as well

Comment: Or add some more digits to the hand-written matrix!

Comment: @BenoitPasquier I was actually trying this out. Replacing the values in the hand-written matrix (test condition) with the actual values from the eigenvector, will render full equality (`==`) `true`. As for `≈` it returns an error because the test condition does not provide enough significant digits.

@BallpointBen Could you add a code example for increasing the tolerance of `isapprox`?

Comment: I don't think that's correct. I tried it right now (copying the values of the eigen vector by hand in the matrix), and it worked. the default `rtol` is about `sqrt(eps()) ≈ 1.5e-8`. For your other question, you can type `isapprox(a, b; atol=..., rtol=...)`. Type `?isapprox` for the documentation at the REPL.

Comment: Try, `@assert isapprox(A_diag, [-128.493    0.0      0.0      0.0       0.0;
    0.0    -55.8878   0.0      0.0       0.0;
    0.0      0.0     42.7522   0.0       0.0;
    0.0      0.0      0.0     87.1611    0.0;
    0.0 0.0      0.0      0.0     542.468], atol=1e-3)
`

Comment: Setting `atol=1e-3` (E.g. `@assert isapprox(A_diag, solution_matrix, atol=1e-3)` does indeed remove the error message. However, the solution provides the values with six significant digits, and not a set number of decimal digits. With this in mind I think setting a relative tolerance of 6 digits is more prudent. Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: Not directly AFAIK. But the IMHO `isapprox` is a better check than what you are looking for. For example, `isapprox(x, y, rtol=1e-5)` is a more appropriate check than a check of 5 significant digits. That's because `isapprox` checks `norm(x-y) <= max(atol, rtol*max(norm(x), norm(y)))` which is more natural and (i) independent of the base (in the linear-algebra sense) of the matrices `x` and `y` and (ii) is independent of the base with which you write numbers (base 10, base 2, and so on).

Comment: @BenoitPasquier I agree, using `rtol` would be appropriate for most purposes. I got hung up in the fact that I could not test two values with a specified number of significant digits, as this is a fairly common "pen-and-paper" practice. In this case I was testing the equality (`==`) of my answer against values provided in the exercise. Therefore, it could be useful to verify whether the values in the solution has been rounded. Regarding the `norm()` function, I struggle with understanding its purpose and what is does. Could you explain this briefly, or is there an ELI5-tutorial somewhere?

Comment: I'm not sure there's much I can say. `norm(x)` simply gives you the norm of `x`. The default is the 2-norm but you can specify which norm. Check the help by typing `?norm` at the REPL and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#p-norm for more details!

Comment: Actually, side note, I take back my comment on base-indepence, since `norm(A)` for matrix `A` is just taking the 2-norm of the vector `A[:]` and does not use `opnorm`. However, `norm` is still better — IMHO — than checking significant digits.